# Add dataframe column containing minimum value of a list

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing three columns, two of which can contain either numeric values or lists. I would like to add additional columns containing the min / max values of each of these two columns. For example, my data frame may look like;

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L), A = structure(list(
    5, c(0.5, 0.6), 2), names = c("", "", "")), B = structure(list(
    c(0.2, 0.3), 6, c(0.1, 0.1)), names = c("", "", ""))), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to mutate this to add the columns;

| ID | A | B | min_A | max_A | min_B | max_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 0.2, 0.3 | 5 | 5 | 0.2 | 0.3 |
| 2 | 0.5, 0.6 | 6 | 0.5 | 0.6 | 6 | 6 |
| 3 | 2 | 0.1, 0.1 | 2 | 2 | 0.1 | 0.1 |

I have tried `mutate(min_A = min(unlist(A)))`, but this seems to take the minimum value of the *entire column of A* rather than just the list on any given row. `mutate(min_A = min(A))` errors out because list is an invalid argument type for the `min` command. So how might I go about adding the data I'm after?

Comment: Please post data in `dput` format. This is specially important when the data is/includes lists. If your data.frame is named `df`, edit the question with the output of `dput(head(df))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `map` with `across`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
 mutate(across(A:B,  ~map_dbl(.x, min), .names = 'min_{.col}'),
       across(A:B, ~ map_dbl(.x, max), .names = 'max_{.col}'))
```

-output

```
 ID        A        B min_A min_B max_A max_B
1  1        5 0.2, 0.3   5.0   0.2   5.0   0.3
2  2 0.5, 0.6        6   0.5   6.0   0.6   6.0
3  3        2 0.1, 0.1   2.0   0.1   2.0   0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

You should able to get the answer by adding `rowwise()`. I also used `across()` in my answer but that part isn't 100% necessary, just a little more efficient:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(across(A:B, function(x) min(unlist(x)), .names = "min_{.col}")) %>%
  mutate(across(A:B, function(x) max(unlist(x)), .names = "max_{.col}"))

# A tibble: 3 × 7
# Rowwise: 
     ID A         B         min_A min_B max_A max_B
  <dbl> <list>    <list>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 <dbl [1]> <dbl [2]>   5     0.2   5     0.3
2     2 <dbl [2]> <dbl [1]>   0.5   6     0.6   6  
3     3 <dbl [1]> <dbl [2]>   2     0.1   2     0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R with a loop:

```
cols <- c("A", "B")
for(col in cols){
  df[,paste0("min_", col)] <- sapply(df[,col], function(x) min(unlist(x)))
  df[,paste0("max_", col)] <- sapply(df[,col], function(x) max(unlist(x)))
}
```